# Site from different location

Tags: web, usability, webtest

Is there any service which provides visuals of how a particular site looks when browsed from different locations across the world. This is useful for testing websites which auto detects users location and show some location based content.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know about service but you can use free proxy(anonymizers) to change your ip address.
it will make you look as if you were from another country. You can choose your "country" by picking
different proxies.

have a look at [this](http://www.proxy4free.com/list/webproxy1.html) list.